# Get PHP code commented as ajax respond instead of executing it and rendering as result

Tags: twig, drupal-8

The Drupal-based website I'm working on has a jQuery $.ajax POST request to custom PHP code. I render node body in my `page.html.twig` as

```
{{ node.body.value|raw }}
```

and it works fine at every page except the page having the PHP code loaded. In its case I get PHP code commented like

```
<!--
echo '...';
-->
```

I've tried the code

```
{% set body = {
    '#type':   'processed_text',
    '#text':    node.body.value,
    '#format':  node.body.format,
} %}
{{ body }}
```

as mentioned on the link https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/238780, but it doesn't help

How to properly execute PHP code and render it as a result on a page?

Comment: You mean you have PHP code inside `node.body.value`?

Comment: Not really. Previous developer inserted inside of node.body.value an ajax POST request to PHP file. I just re-written the page code, so the issue is no longer actual. However, I would like to know how to resolve similar problems in the future

Comment: It makes no senses that an ajax call would return (raw) PHP code though. If the server sends back PHP instead of executing it, then something is wrong with configuration. Was the ajax call perhaps pointing to a file not ending in `.php`?

Comment: The file has the extension .php, its code is executed on shared hosting and ajax call fetches the result of the execution. But the code is not executed on my local WAMP server, so probably yes - something is wrong with configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use HTML comments for PHP code. Use PHP comment instead.

**NOT RECOMMANDED**, Example with HTML comment
Note: HTML comment are present in return HTML file, but not rendered

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div><!-- <?php echo $myVariable; ?> --></div>
  <body>
<html>
```

**RECOMMANDED**, Example with PHP comment

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div><?php /* echo $myVariable; */ ?></div>
  <body>
<html>
```

PHP comment are absent in return HTML file. Return HTML will be :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  <body>
<html>
```

Comment: This is not OP's issue. The issue is that the PHP code gets auto-commented by drupal/twig instead of getting executed